# Setting "SameSite=None" to cookie in Java

Tags: java, cookies, header, samesite

i have the following cookie:

```
Cookie chatter = new Cookie("cookieName");
chatter.setMaxAge(2592000);
chatter.setPath("/");
response.addCookie(chatter);
```

I am trying to add `SameSite=None; Secure` to it by doing `response.setHeader("Set-Cookie", "SameSite=None; Secure");` before I add it, but it doesn't seem to work.

Any idea how to set it up correctly?